# Batch removing part of filenames using Automator

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I'm trying to create an Automator script that removes portion of a filename after a delimeter while preserving the extension.

Files are usually called like 1-cropped_DSC5888.jpg, 2-cropped_Whatsapp75.png etc. I want to remove everything after _ and keep only the part with number and '-cropped' so like: 1-cropped.jpg

I tried it with this script

```
on run {input, parameters}
try
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}
    set theFileNameList to {}
    repeat with thisItem in input
        set the end of theFileNameList to text item 2 of (thisItem as text)
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
    return theFileNameList
on error eStr number eNum
    display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 with icon caution
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
    return
end try
```

end run

But this removes the part I want to keep and keeps the part I want to delete. Also it gives me just an output, but doesn't rename the actual files. Any help with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing is returning a list of the *last* part of the names (if there is more than one delimiter character, the *second* part) to the next action.

Text item delimiters aren't really needed if you are just using the first occurrence of a character, so you can do something like:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to {}
    repeat with anItem in input
        set {theFolder, oldName, extension} to getNamePieces from anItem
        try
            set here to offset of "_" in oldName
            set newName to text 1 thru (here - 1) of oldName
            tell application "Finder" to set name of anItem to (newName & extension)
            set end of output to (theFolder & newName & extension) as alias
        on error errmess -- don't rename if error (delimiter not found, duplicate file, etc)
            log errmess
            set end of output to anItem as alias
        end try
    end repeat
    return output -- for next action
end run

to getNamePieces from someItem
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (someItem as text)
        set |container| to path of container
        set {|name|, extension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if extension is not "" then
        set |name| to text 1 thru -((count extension) + 2) of |name| -- just the name part
        set extension to "." & extension
    end if
    return {container, |name|, extension}
end getNamePieces
```